# Convergence of Sum of Squares of Sequence with Fixed Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

For any given $n$, suppose we have a partition of $1$, i.e. a finite sequence $a_{n,1}, a_{n,2}, \ldots, a_{n,n}$ such that $0 \leq a_{n,i} < 1$ for all $i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n a_{n,i} = 1$. Suppose also that this partition gets increasingly fine: formally, $\max_{1\leq i\leq n} a_{n,i} \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Is it true that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_{n,i}^2 \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$? If so, how can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{n,i}^{2} \leq (\max_{1\leq i \leq n} a_{n,i}) \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{n,i}=\max_{1\leq i \leq n} a_{n,i} \to 0$.